# Check if file exists before showing image?

Tags: php, html

I need to make an image gallery with a variable number of images. I'm making a loop that checks for a lot of image names, like image1, image2, image3 and so on.

I need to make a condition so that it doesn't show a missing file icon if an image doesn't exists. How can I check if the file exists and if true show it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are several PHP functions that will let you check for the existence of a file.  One of them is [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

Another function that you can use is [`is_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php).  According to the documentation:

> Returns TRUE if the filename exists
>   and is a regular file, FALSE
>   otherwise.

So in your code you can do something like:

```
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    // do stuff with file
}

// OR

if (is_file($fileName)) {
    // do stuff with file
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) is your friend.